# What to set displayedPropertyKeys for CNContactPickerViewController in ios9

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts, abaddressbook, addressbookui

For lower than ios9, I used to write

```
picker.displayedProperties = @[@(kABPersonEmailProperty)];
```

For ios9, what will be the [displayedPropertyKeys](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContactPickerViewController/displayedPropertyKeys)
(    `picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[@(????)];`
)

Note:- picker is `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` for ios8 and `CNContactPickerViewController` for ios9.

I am basically fetching the contacts using `Contacts framework`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Metadata_Keys ?

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Day saviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

**Objective-C**

```
picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
```

**Swift 5.2**

```
picker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
```

A full list of available keys can be found at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/contact_keys.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I also came across https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Metadata_Keys for all metadata keys.

Comment: Please, fix your post. It's not an array of NSNumber, but an array of NSString: picker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactEmailAddressesKey];